# Distinguishing and substituting decimals in Perl

Tags: regex, perl, substitution

I want to substitute decimals from commas to fullstops in a file and I wanted to try to do this in perl. 
An example of my dataset looks something like this:

```
Species_1:0,12, Species_2:0,23, Species_3:2,53
```

I want to substitute the decimals but not all commas such that:

```
Species_1:0.12, Species_2:0.23, Species_3:2.53
```

I was thinking it might work using the substitution function like such:

```
$comma_file= "Species_1:0,12 , Species_2:0,23, Species_3:2,53"

    $comma = "(:\d+/,\d)";
#match a colon, any digits after the colon, the wanted comma and digits preceding it
       if ($comma_file =~ m/$comma/g) {
           $comma_file =~ tr/,/./;
        }
print "$comma_file\n";
```

However, when I tried this, what happened was that all my commas changed into fullstops, not just the ones I was targetting. Is it an issue with the regex or am I just not doing the match substitution correctly?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This :

```
use strict;
use warnings;
my $comma_file = "Species_1:0,12, Species_2:0,23, Species_3:2,53";
$comma_file =~ s/(\d+),(\d+)/$1.$2/g;
print $comma_file, "\n";
```

Yields :

```
Species_1:0.12, Species_2:0.23, Species_3:2.53
```

The regex searches for commas having at least one digit on both sides and replaces them with a dot.

Your code doesn’t work because you first check for commas surrounded by digits, and, if ok, you then replace ALL commas with dots

Comment: Good, but the space after the first term (legitimate since it is actually introduced in your sample line), may confuse one when looking at the output.  Perhaps remove it altogether?

Comment: @zdim : thanks for checking ! Indeed that's confusing and doesn't match the OP. Edited my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

From the shown data it appears that a comma to be replaced must always have a number on each side, and that every such occurrence  need be replaced. There is a fine [answer by GMB](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53584613/4653379).

Another way for this kind of a problem is to use [lookarounds](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html#Looking-ahead-and-looking-behind)

```
$comma_file =~ s/(?<=[0-9]),(?=[0-9])/./g;
```

which should be more efficient, as there is no copying into `$1` and `$2` and no quantifiers.

My benchmark

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';

use Benchmark qw(cmpthese);

my $str = q(Species_1:0,12, Species_2:0,23, Species_3:2,53);

sub subs {
    my ($str) = @_; 
    $str =~ s/(\d+),(\d+)/$1.$2/g;
    return $str;
}

sub look {
    my ($str) = @_; 
    $str =~ s/(?<=\d),(?=\d)/./g;
    return $str;
}

die "Output not equal" if subs($str) ne look($str);

cmpthese(-3, {
    subs => sub { my $res = subs($str) },
    look => sub { my $res = look($str) },
});
```

with output

```
         Rate subs look
subs 256126/s   -- -46%
look 472677/s  85%   --
```

This is only one, particular, string but the efficiency advantage should only increase with the length of the string, while longer patterns (numbers here) should reduce that a little.

Comment: Nice solution, a bit more complicated to understand but sure faster

Comment: @GMB Agreed, yours is far easier to recommend to someone unaccustomed to regex.  It is also probably easier to modify in general if requirements are refined/changed since it captures the whole thing. (For example, you can just prepend `:` in the first capture in the matching part, to further restrict what need be changed.)